# Is there an easy way to match 3 fields with jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need to compare 3 fields with jquery validate to ensure they match.  If they don't match, I need all three fields to be hightlighted in error.  Is there a relatively simple way to do this?

Comment: Which specific validation plugin (if any) are you using?

Comment: @Yardboy http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the equalTo validation method to require that one element's value be the same as that of another element. So, you'll need two of these, one pointing to each of the other two fields. However, I think you would only need to put them on one of the three fields.

Sample, taken from the [plugin's documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/equalTo#other):

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    password: "required",
    password_again: {
      equalTo: "#password"
    }
  }
});
```